# Cart details not getting in mini cart

Tags: magento2, blocks, mini-cart

For some purpose (something like popup) I'm trying to fetch cart details in minicart.phtml from **Magento2\vendor\magento\module-checkout\view\frontend\templates\cart\minicart.phtml**.

I directly modified core file just for checking purpose only. The point is cart details (from below code) are displaying only in cart page. It is not displaying in other pages like home page, product, category pages.I'm using default Magento EE 2.2.5 Luma theme. Any suggestion will be appreciated...

Below is my code (It's dirty, just for checking purpose),

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$cart = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart'); 

// get quote items collection
$itemsCollection = $cart->getQuote()->getItemsCollection();

// get array of all items what can be display directly
$itemsVisible = $cart->getQuote()->getAllVisibleItems();

// get quote items array
$items = $cart->getQuote()->getAllItems();

foreach($items as $item) {
    echo 'ID: '.$item->getProductId().'<br />';
    echo 'Name: '.$item->getName().'<br />';
    echo 'Sku: '.$item->getSku().'<br />';
    echo 'Quantity: '.$item->getQty().'<br />';
    echo 'Price: '.$item->getPrice().'<br />';
    echo "<br />";            
}
```

I tried with block also through the constructor (like proper way) `magento2ee\vendor\magento\module-checkout\Block\Onepage.php` But same like working only in cart page. Not in other pages..

**Update:**

I'm just wondering below piece of code for fetching product details is working but not for cart.

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$productCollection = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection');
/** Apply filters here */
$collection = $productCollection->addAttributeToSelect('*')
            ->load();

foreach ($collection as $product){
     echo 'Name  =  '.$product->getName().'<br>';
     break;
}
```

Comment: try with `$objectManager->create` instead of `$objectManager->get`

Comment: @KeyurShah Thanks for your comment, I tried with that also. But it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

Little Modifications in your code. 
Not sure but it should work I had same issue while ago.

Little modifications in your method.

You can give a try with `Magento\Checkout\Model\Session`.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but I already tried with Session also. Still it doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

We are using below code on our custom phtml file which is located under

> /view/frontend/templates/checkout/cart/custom.phtml

```
$om =   \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();

//Getting cart Item//

$quote = $om->create('Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart')->getQuote();
$quoteitems = $quote->getAllVisibleItems();
```

You can try this one.

Comment: I want to have with minicart.phtml so that it will available in all pages.

Comment: The main reason of not showing the data on minicart at other pages are coming from cache and you need to alter the mini cart content by using standard Knockout JS concept. Cart page wont come from cache and system is fetching and showing your information on the fly of render. Please refer the below post which may give some better idea. https://webkul.com/blog/how-to-show-additional-data-on-mini-cart-in-magento-2/

Answer (score 1):

Get cart items from customer local storage. 
And render it using knock out.

You can get Cart item details of the guest user also,

in your js file

```
define([
        'jquery',
        'knockout',
        'Magento_Customer/js/customer-data',
        'uiComponent'
    ], function ($, ko, customerData, Component) {
        return Component.extend({
            initialize: function () {
                self = this;
                self.cart = customerData.get('cart');

                let cartData = self.cart().items ? self.cart().items: [];

                cartData.map(function(item) {
                    console.log(item.product_id);
                    console.log(item.product_name);
                    console.log(item.product_sku);
                });

            },

        });
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. But I'm considering Guest users also.

Comment: Bro you can get Cart item details of guest user also

Comment: Thanks it's working fine. And can you tell how to get quote id from this ? It's have Item id like 126 but quote id some thing like   8e57755dd722b331c26f2e500e61fc9a    . Any Idea ?I need to get shipping estimates from API.. eg   http://localhost:81/rest/default/V1/guest-carts/8e57755dd722b331c26f2e500e61fc9a/estimate-shipping-methods

Comment: Hi Elavarasan, if quote id is missing then add it by creating an after plugin of Magento\Checkout\CustomerData\Cart:: getSectionData