# Magento 2 how to get current cart details and customer cart details?

Tags: magento2, cart, mini-cart

In Magento 2 how to get current cart details without customer login and get cart details with customer login like minicart ?

I checked with this `\Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart` & `\Magento\Checkout\Model\Session` both are not working

I want to get this(cart details) on my custom page(or my custom popup)

I already searched and checked in magento stackexchange,magento community and others blog not get actual results.

I am using this code -

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$cart = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart'); 

// retrieve quote items collection
$itemsCollection = $cart->getQuote()->getItemsCollection();

// get array of all items what can be display directly
$itemsVisible = $cart->getQuote()->getAllVisibleItems();

// retrieve quote items array
$items = $cart->getQuote()->getAllItems();

foreach($items as $item) {
    echo 'ID: '.$item->getProductId().'<br />';
    echo 'Name: '.$item->getName().'<br />';
    echo 'Sku: '.$item->getSku().'<br />';
    echo 'Quantity: '.$item->getQty().'<br />';
    echo 'Price: '.$item->getPrice().'<br />';
    echo "<br />";            
}
```

That code only working on cart page but not working in other pages.
That code is also fine when cache disable but how it will works without cache disable ?

Comment: Post your code here @sumeetbaja

Comment: @PrathapGunasekaran please check now

Comment: Which type of product you have in cart?

Comment: @AshishViradiya there only simple products .
Above code working only on cart page but not working in other pages.

Comment: Where did you want to place the code?

Comment: @ARUNPRABAKARANM on header file
it is working fine when cache disable but how it will works without cache disable ?

Comment: I can get cart details in an external script when cache enable

Comment: would you please tell how ?

Comment: I hope the following link will be helpful for you https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/257524

Comment: are you check my code? If not working Please tell which pthml to place code

Comment: yes i checked your code it is same like my code but that code is not working when cache enable

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92248/discussion-between-arunprabakaran-m-and-sumeet-bajaj).

Comment: in that case your cache is disable but i need when cache is enable

Comment: No, the cache is enabled in my site

Comment: ok but it will not show in other pages,would you please write that code in your custom page or other files except cart & checkout page.

Comment: Yes, bro. You can get those details when only products are in a cart. Once product cart session over you can't get. So it's not a cache issue

Comment: i know that things

Comment: Tell your phtml file path and file name.It will be helpful to identify issue

Comment: /var/www/html/xyz/app/design/frontend/AAA/theme/Magento_Theme/templates/html/header.phtml

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92251/discussion-between-arunprabakaran-m-and-sumeet-bajaj).

Comment: Please check updated link

Comment: ok checking and let you know

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92258/discussion-on-question-by-sumeet-bajaj-magento-2-how-to-get-current-cart-details).

Comment: @AmitBera
Do you know how can we get cart details in custom module page ?